# select value of 2 html select element witht the jquery

Tags: jquery

I have a situation where i have to select the dropdown value like this

```
$(this).parent().parent('div').find('option:selected').val();
```

later i realized that i need to put 2nd ddl there in the same div, so now i become confuse how to fetch the value of each of this DDL. is there a way to apply id for this code

```
$(this).parent().parent('div').find('option:selected').val();
```

so that i can fetch each.

following is my code
this is first ddl.

```
<select style="width:30px" name="ddlQty" id="ddlQty" class="positive-integer"><option value="0">0</option>
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="3">3</option>
<option value="4">4</option>
<option value="5">5</option>
<option value="6">6</option>
<option value="7">7</option>
<option value="8">8</option>
<option value="9">9</option>
</select>
```

and this is second

```
<select name="OptionID" id="OptionID"><option value="14">5''  £25.00</option>
</select>
```

how can i select each of this value?

Comment: What is the context for `this`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the fisrt one:

```
$(this).parent().parent('div').find('#ddlQty option:selected').val();
```

And the second one:

```
$(this).parent().parent('div').find('#OptionID option:selected').val();
```

Comment: If he's using the ID, it's not needed to traverse the DOM... ID should be unique

Comment: @gustavohenke, the OP might need to get it in relation to `this` (like if it's an event)

Comment: but in my dom there are multiple div with the 2 ddl having the same id thats y i had to do like this.

Comment: @NoviceToDotNet, should never have multiple elements with the same id. Id's should be unique... if not, use classes

Comment: no i have 2 different id in a div for 2 different ddl but that in being drawn multiple times.

Comment: if a div is being drawn multiple times with the same id, you do not have unique id's. if you show the context of your html and js you could probably get a more precise answer.

Answer (score 5):

If Id's are unique *as it should*

```
$('#ddlQty').val();
```

and

```
$('#OptionID').val();
```

Comment: okay, except it appears the OP is wanting to get it in relation to `this`

Comment: It's ID, supposed to be unique, no need to reference it with `this`

Comment: what i mean is maybe he shouldn't be getting it by id at all. if his js is within an event function, he might want to get a select in relation to whatever object fired the event. why else would he be using `this`?

Answer (score 2):

```
$('#ddlQty').val();
$('#OptionID').val();
```

would get the value of each select menu.

Answer (score 1):

IDs should be unique, so you shouldn't need the `$(this).parent().parent('div')` part. The following should work

```
$('#ddlQty').val();
$('#OptionID').val();
```